How do I fix gcloud compute ssh command after Google Cloud CLI update to 478.0.0?
I'm not able to determine why after updating google cloud cli I'm not able to establish ssh connections with iap flag set.
On cli/sdk version 477.0.0 this works but not with version 478.0.0
gcloud compute ssh some-resource --tunnel-through-iap --project some-project --zone some-zone

Connection never starts and error thrown by 478.0.0 is:
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255]
When I run the command with the --troubleshoot flag the only "error like" output is related to no direct network connectivity (which is expected and the reason I'm using iap the tunnel)
Thanks in advance
I tried running the troubleshoot suggestions that the cli tool mentioned.
Googled around.
And tried to find some kind of "official" google issue tracking of the google cloud cli, but didn't found anything useful.
Then downgrading the version of the cli to 477.0.0 "fixed the problem"
